# How to control order of extension item in Chrome context menu

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, contextmenu

Is there a way to control the order that my Chrome extension's context menu item appears in?

It probably can't appear above any of the Chrome's built in context menu items (like "Open link in new tab", etc.), but maybe there is a way to control where it appears among other extensions' context menu entries?

Probably not, because in all likelihood all makers of extensions want their's to be above all others, but just in case I'm wrong.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The context menu entries are ordered alphabetically. This means that if you name your context entry something like `AAWhatever`, the likelihood of your entry being at the top is pretty high. I know of no other way to control the position of your entry using only your extension.

Comment: This answer is not very precise. Ordering of context menu is alphabetically but based on extension's `name` in the manifest.json and not the naming of the actual context menu item.

Comment: @therealmarv not true

Comment: @therealmarv if your context menus doesn't have sub context menus then name of extension isn't used, so I can have different name of context menu for a page or for a link, and their order will be different

Answer (score 2):

#### The accepted answer is only *partially correct*:

When you **create** multiple context menus(items) in your extension, and their **contexts** are set, such that they appear simultaneously, then the order in which they appear in the menu is dependent on the order in which the items(menus) are created.

Therefore, you can control order, by being mindful of not only the order you create them in, but then setting the `contexts` parameter to hide them upon creation, then display them when needed using `chrome.contextMenus.update()` with a different `contexts` value... this will give the appearance of **inserting** menus and/or moving them around if done properly.